# What are moments and why do we need them?

Tags: probability-distributions, soft-question

I am learning probability and have a question about moment generating functions. So far I've learned how to calculate them and how to find the nth moment of a probability distribution. My question is, what are moments? When the question asks "Find the nth moment of a probability distribution" what is it asking for (physical meaning) and why would you want to find this?
I understand $M'x(0) = E[X]$ and $M''x(0) = E[X^2]$ but I don't see how its helpful finding higher orders of $Mx(t)$. Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 2):

If $\mu$ is the probability measure then the moments are the integrals $$\int x^n\text{d}\mu(x).$$

The moments are then linear functionals on the probability measure. Knowing these values, [sometimes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_problem), allows you to uniquely determine $\mu$.

Notice how in that case the is an improvement in the nature of the information that you need to handle: The moments are just a sequence of numbers which is containing all the information of the probability measure, which is a function on measurable sets (often there are uncountable many measurable sets).

You can read about interpretations for a few of the first moments, [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment_%28mathematics%29).